# Attempt to present VC on VC which is already presenting (null)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` where I am adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to each `UICollectionViewCell`.

On tap, I am performing a **segue** and presenting another `UIViewController`. It appears when I tap, the selector function is invoked several times, which is why the following warning is logged:

> Warning: Attempt to present VC on VC which is already presenting (null)

1. I have a **segue identifier** in **storyboard** connecting the two **VCs**
2. I am not using either the `didSelectCell`/`didDeSelectCell` delegate methods
3. The gesture is only added in the `cellForItemAt` delegate method

I am admittedly lost on what the root cause is triggering the multiple invocations and would appreciate any help as I could not find anything directly similar to reference in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Not sure if it has to do anything with the cell being reused?

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! collectionViewCell

    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap))
    tap.delegate = self
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return cell
}

    @objc func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        homeCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender: sender)        
}

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let presentedVC = segue.destination as? viewController, let sender = sender as? UITapGestureRecognizer, let cell = sender.view as? collectionViewCell {
       //Data passed
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are adding tap gesture, you should use UICollectionView didSelectItem delegate method to handle the cell touch action.

Comment: cells are reused and you're adding the gesture again and again. thats why it is called multiple times.

Comment: @vivekDas i added a tap gesture because i have the cell handling another pan gesture that is added as well, is using the didSelectItem delegate still the way to go here?

Comment: you can still use didSelectItem delegate method as tap gesture with other pan gesture. Apart form this you can create your custom UICollectionViewCell and  override prepareForReuse() method, and in this method just remove the added tap gesture.